# Get previous version settings for C# application

Tags: c#

I have an old Winforms application that stores user settings. I have completely rewritten the application in WPF and would like to migrate the settings. I can't use the Upgrade() method since I have changed the names of most of the user settings. I found the GetPreviousVersion() method but it fails since the old settings no longer exist in the new application. Also, the applications are in different namespace's which I hear causes some issues.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Why not open up the original application and run Upgrade() just to see the results it produces?  You could then also try GetPreviousVersion() too.

Comment: Upgrade works on my original application, that's what I had been using. But my new app has a different namespace and so it doesn't see the original app settings. I need to know how to look up settings from essentially another app.